# how to change color of vim cursor in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vim, colors, vsvim, text-cursor

I have installed the Vim key bindings extension in Visual Studio 2010. I also have a color scheme setup with a dark background. This creates a problem since Vim key bindings extension has set my cursor to black, which is against a dark background .... not good. How can I change that cursor to a different color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you are using VsVim then I had the same problem. Eventually worked out that I needed to change the `VsVim Block Caret` display item under Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display items. I changed the foreground color to 'Gray' and the background color to 'White' (which seems back to front) but that looks good for me on a dark background.

Comment: truly, I love you Mr. Steve.  This has been driving me batty for quite awhile.

Comment: I found that setting both foreground and background to Automatic will work in all color schemes (perhaps this should have been the default)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for!  In VS2012, VsVim Block Caret is under Fonts and Colors for Text Editor.

Answer (score 3):

for those who hit upon this question in future - You can change the block caret color settings in Tools > Options > VsVim > Defaults > Item Colors > Block Caret